# While creating new mysite in sharepoint set database

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Im wondering if there is a way i can tell what database i want the new mysite to be create in.

In our server we have multiple databases for mysites `SP_MySiteContent00` and `SP_MySiteContent01` and so on. But the script below creates them all in `SP_MySiteContent` by default.

Anyone know how can tell what database it should use?

This is my code:

```
param
(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$username,
[string]$database
)

asnp *sh*


$mysite = (Get-SPSite)[0]

$context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($mysite)
$upm =  New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

#Create user profile
$profile = $upm.ResolveProfile($username)

if(!$profile)
{
Write-Host "$profile does not have a profile. Can't create personal site"
}

elseif($profile)
{
    if($profile.PersonalSite -eq $Null)
    {
     $profile.CreatePersonalSite()
     Write-Host "Personal site created"
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Warning "$username already has a personal site"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no way to specify content databases directly (see: [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61057/self-service-site-creation-e-g-mysites-specify-content-db)), but one possible way to control which content database the new mysite is created in is to set all other content databases to offline mode.

If, for example, the databases you listed above were all you had and you wanted to create a site in "SP_MySiteContent01" you would do:

```
Get-SPContentDatabase “SP_MySiteContent” | Set-SPContentDatabase –Status 1
Get-SPContentDatabase “SP_MySiteContent00” | Set-SPContentDatabase –Status 1
$profile.CreatePersonalSite()
Get-SPContentDatabase “SP_MySiteContent” | Set-SPContentDatabase –Status 0
Get-SPContentDatabase “SP_MySiteContent00” | Set-SPContentDatabase –Status 0
```

Also see [Setting ShaerPoint content databases offline via Script](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ramg/2012/05/09/setting-sharepoint-content-databases-offline-via-script/)